# Lightning flow builder and lightning components

Tags: lightning, visual-workflow

I want to pass the values from a lightning component to a flow. This value will be displayed as a default value on the display text.
Is this achievable ? Can someone please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. We can invoke the flow from lightning component and can pass the variables as well to flow. Please refer this [doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.216.0.salesforce_vpm_guide.meta/salesforce_vpm_guide/components_using_flow_inputs_set.htm).

Comment: Thank You very much for your help.I have tried this in my code but unfortunately there is no result.Can you help me with the code? Also, What changes do we need to make at the flow end?